# Kendo UI datasource not triggering transport :Create

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've 2 kendoUI grids doing CRUD from a web service. For some reason, read command works perfectly and populates my grid. But the create is not triggering in the UserEventGrid() method.
Here is my current situation. I have a grid that displays first. When I click on Add it opens a lookup grid when I select an item from that grid it opens a window with the selected row. That has
a Add button. Now when I click on this Add the transport : Create is not triggered.

UserEventGrid() this is the main Grid[First Grid].This has addentry button(It triggers addEntry(e))
namesListGrid() this is the second grid that populates after clicking lookup. After selecting row on the new window it has add button.(It triggers add(dataItem) and respective transport . Here comes the 
issue. It's not triggering the transport Create.

Below is my code.

```
    function UserEventGrid() {
        userDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    return JSON.parse(response.d); 
                },
                model: {
                    id: "UserId",
                    fields: {
                        UserId: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                        FirstName: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                        LastName: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                },
            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Services/Services.asmx/getUsers", 
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                    type: "POST", 
                },
                create: {
                    url: "/Services/Services.asmx/AddUsers",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json"
                    },
                update: {
                    url: "/Services/Services.asmx/UpdateUsers",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "/Services/Services.asmx/DeleteUsers",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if ((type == "update") || (type == "create") || (type == "destroy")) {
                        console.log('parameterMap: data => ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                        return JSON.stringify({ "erpUserJson": data });
                    } else {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        userGrid = $("#user-event-grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: userDS,
            height: 450,
            pageable: false,
            sortable: true,
            autosync: true,
            binding: true,
            columns: [
                  {
                      field: "Active",
                      title: "Active",
                      headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">Active</span>',
                      template: '<input type="checkbox" #= Active ? "checked=checked" : "" # disabled="disabled" ></input>',
                      attributes: {
                          style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                      },
                      width: 65
                  },
                  {
                      field: "FirstName",
                      title: "FirstName",
                      headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">FirstName</span>',
                      attributes: {
                          style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      field: "LastName",
                      title: "LastName",
                      headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">LastName</span>',
                      attributes: {
                          style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                      }
                  },
     ,
                    {
                        command: [
                          {
                              name: "destroy",
                              template: "<div class='k-button delete-btn'><span class='k-icon k-delete'></span></div>",
                              text: "remove"
                          },
                          {
                              text: "Edit",
                              template: "<div class='k-button edit-btn'><span class='k-icon k-edit'></span></div>",
                              click: editEntry
                          },

                        ],
                        width: 90,
                        attributes: {
                            style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"
                        }
                    },
            ],
            editable: "popup"
        }).data('kendoGrid');
    }

    function namesListGrid() {
        nameDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    return JSON.parse(response.d); 
                },
                model: { 
                    id: "Z_CIM_WRK_ID",
                    fields: {
                        Z_NAMEFIRST: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                        Z_NAMELAST: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                        EMAILID: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "string" },

                    }
                },
            },
           transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Services/Services.asmx/getNames",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: getSearchCriteria()
                },
       parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if ((type == "read") || (type == "create") || (type == "destroy")) {
                        console.log("parametermap => " + JSON.stringify(data));
                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                    } else {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        namesGrid = $("#second").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: nameDS,
            height: 450,
            pageable: false,
            sortable: true,
            binding: true,
            selectable: "row",
            serverFiltering: true,
            autoSync: true,
            columns: [
                      {
                          field: "Z_EID",
                          title: "ID",
                          headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">ID</span>',
                          attributes: {
                              style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          field: "Z_NAMELAST",
                          title: "ZNAMELAST",
                          headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">ZNAMELAST</span>',
                          attributes: {
                              style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                          }
                      },
                    {
                        field: "Z_NAMEFIRST",
                        title: "ZNAMEFIRST",
                        headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">ZNAMEFIRST</span>',
                        attributes: {
                            style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                        }
                    },
           ],
            change: function (e) {
                var dataItem = this.dataItem(this.select());

                $("#third").hide(true);
                $("#second").hide(true);
                $("#first").show(true);
                $("#gtable").show(true);
                add(dataItem);

            }

        }).data('kendoGrid');

    }



      function add(dataItem) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(dataItem));
         var model = {
             "UserId": dataItem.Z_EID,
             "FirstName": dataItem.Z_NAMEFIRST,
             "LastName": dataItem.Z_NAMELAST,
             "Group": "OPS",
             "EmailAddr": dataItem.EMAILID,
             "MobilePhone": dataItem.PHONE,
             };


         var viewModel = kendo.observable({

             data: model,
             isAddMode: true,
             isLookupMode:false,
             isEditMode: false,
             groups: userGroups,
             closeWin: function (dataItem) {
                 console.log('data => ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
                 console.log("BEFORE => " + JSON.stringify(userDS.data()));
                 userDS.add(this.data);
                 userDS.sync();
                 var editWin = $("#window");
                 editWin.data("kendoWindow").close();

             },
               });

         kendo.bind($("#edit-win"), viewModel);

         $("#palette").html('');
         $("#palette").append('<div id="palette-widget"></div>');


         $('#window').data("kendoWindow").center().open();
 }

  function addEntry(e) {
             var model = {
                 "UserId": "",
                 "FirstName": '',
                 "LastName": '',
                      };

             var viewModel = kendo.observable({

                 data: model,
                 isAddMode: false,
                 isLookupMode:true,
                 isEditMode: false,
                 filterable:true,
                 groups: userGroups,
                 closeWin: function (e) {
                     console.log('data => ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
                     userDS.add(this.data);
                      var editWin = $("#window");
                     editWin.data("kendoWindow").close();
                     e.preventDefault();
                 },
                 LookupWin: function (e) {
                     namesListGrid();

                      },
                   });

             kendo.bind($("#edit-win"), viewModel);

             $("#palette").html('');
             $("#palette").append('<div id="palette-widget"></div>');


             $('#window').data("kendoWindow").center().open();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `addEntry` function, you do add data to the dataSource like this:

```
userDS.add(this.data);
```

However, you never call the `userDS.sync()` (you do it in the `add` function but not `addEntry`).  You did set the `autosync` property to true, which would have triggered the create event, but instead of doing on the `userDS` dataSource, you did it on the `userGrid`.  You can either set the `autosync` to true in the `userDS` dataSource or call the `userDS.sync()` after the `userDS.add`.

Comment: Its not working there is no change even after addding thr autosync() to true on UserDS

Comment: Does the data gets added to the grid even if the create function isn't called?

Comment: Yes, when i click on add  but when i refresh the page its not added to grid

Comment: If you look at the network in the browser's console, do you see any post following the `sycn`?

Comment: I dont see any POST at all only i see GET

Comment: I solved it by using ajax call .Amyways thanks for your try Smurf

Comment: Glad to see you solved it.... you should consider answering your own question in case someone else has the same problem.